# 'to treat' vs 'to treat of'

Tags: difference

> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205381?rskey=o1th5v&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) [2.] a. {intransitive} To deal with some matter in speech or writing; to discourse. (In quot. 1517   transf. of pictorial representation.) Const. ***of***, formerly also ***on, upon***

What are the similarities and differences? Which definition of [**'of'**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) fits?
Is **of** a preposition or a particle?

I encountered this verb phrase below, but notice that the quoted clause with the bold originates from OED's entry on the suffix [-*logy*](http://www.oed.com/109868?rskey=8apr1Y&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid).

> [-logy:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-logy&allowed_in_frame=0)     word-forming element meaning "a speaking, discourse, treatise, doctrine, theory, science," from Greek *-logia* (often via French *-logie* or Medieval Latin *-logia*), from root of *legein* "to speak;"  thus, "the character or deportment of one who speaks or **treats of** (a certain subject);" see [lecture](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-logy&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.).

Another example is the title of [chapter one of Oliver Twist](https://americanliterature.com/author/charles-dickens/book/oliver-twist/chapter-i)

> **Treats of** the Place Where Oliver Twist Was Born and of the Circumstances Attending His Birth

Comment: Good find. But the questions are specific and different. This asks to compare and contrast *treat* with *treat of,* wheras the related question you reference asks about the meaning of *treat* in context.

Comment: "Treat of" is an archaism that survives in some academic prose.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(treat+of)&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28treat%20of%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Both *speak* and *treat* (meaning discuss) can be used either with objects (transitively) or without them (intransitively).

One can speak something--*speak the truth.* It is more common to use *speak* without an object.

*Treat of (something)* is relatively less common than *treat (something).*

*Treat of* is not a phrasal verb because its meaning can be readily understood in terms of adding denotations of its constituents: treat of = (essentially) talk + about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dictionary listing that makes it pretty clear: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/treat

We see that *treat of* is a special construction that has a special meaning.  But it's rarely used now.  I don't think I've ever used it in my whole life!

I also speak Spanish, and Spanish has an exact equivalent, which *is* used frequently -- *Este artículo trata de la Guerra Fría* (= this article is about the Cold War).

You could distinguish this construction from other ways of using the word *treat* by associating this with the word *treatise* ("A systematic, usually extensive written discourse on a subject").  A treatise is long and formal, and *treat of* is formal.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer noted, Spanish uses a similar construction. It's worth noting that French does so as well, and this is likely the source of the usage in English. *"Traiter de"* is common, though the verb can also be used alone with the same meaning: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/traiter [traiter II.A](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/traiter). The construction with *de* emphasizes the formal, methodical nature of the action.

Ultimately, I suspect both derive from the post-Aug. Latin *tracto+de+ablative*" construction. This may have been influenced by the more common use of verbs like *dissero* with *de.* The French cognate *disserter* (like the English "dissertate") is synonymous with *traiter de* in this formal sense and also takes a preposition.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Because StackExchange is a Q&A site, we ask that all answer posts try to answer the question being asked. The etymological information you gave here is an interesting supplement to the other answers, but it does not directly address the question, so it is not a full answer in and of itself. For more details, please see [the Help page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.